# Where is the Great Britain in the Vedic universe?

Tags: geography

I presume, it should be on the Bhū-mandala, but can we be more specific? The colonists tried to insert Britain into the scriptures as a Švēta-dvīpa, which it is definitely not. The real **Švēta-dvīpa** is described in Brahma-samhitā as *adbhuta*, full with cintāmani gems, where every step is a dance and every word is a song.

Šrīmad-bhāgavatam 5th canto describes the features of bhū-mandala, including the 7 islands. On the central island, Jambūdvīpa, nine varšas or lands are also described. Is it reasonable to claim that England is a part of Bhārata-varša? If not, then where else could it be?

To refute this proposal, Šrīmad-bhāgavatam 12th canto, chapter 1 describes the future kings, including Nanda, Candragupta Maurya, Ašoka and others, which are well known also by western historians. SB says they will enjoy the Earth (bhokšyanti pIthivīm) or control it (iyam bhūmir
yāsyati). We know their control never extended to Europe, which makes Europe/England not to be a part of Bhūmi?!!